# How do I put a password to stop the download of an app

Tags: applications, password, data-transfer

I have an iPad for my children and I want to stop them downloading the YouTube app. Can I put a password on their iPad to stop them downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent them from accessing the App Store by restricting access to it:

**Settings** -- **General** -- **Restrictions**

A passcode needs to be set, keep it at a safe place as any other password.